# ajax call gives Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am getting the following error on button click.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at
jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend
jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend
jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend
jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend
jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend
jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend
```

at this line "argtoUpdate = JSON.stringify(response2.name);"

in the following CODE:

```
   $.ajax({
                url: 'http://tales.appedoncp.com/appcp/sanchita/api/sample.php',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: {"json" : input_string},
                success: function(response)
                {
                    for(var i=0; i<response.names.length; i++)
                    {
                     $("#center_brp").append("<div id=\"word\"" + [i]+ " class=\"sample_words\">" + response.names[i] + "</div><br>");
                    }
                    var input = JSON.stringify(response.names);

                    $.ajax({

                        url: 'http://tales.appedoncp.com/appcp/sanchita/api/getSoundsFromWords.php',
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        data: {'words' : input},
                        success: function(response2)
                        {
                            for(var i=0; i<response2.name.length; i++)
                            {
                             $("#center_brp2").append("<div id=\"word\"" + [i]+ " class=\"sample_words\">" + response2.name[i] + "</div><br>");
                            }

                            ***argtoUpdate = JSON.stringify(response2.name);***
                        }

                    });                             


                },
                error: function(e){
                console.log(e);

                }
            });
            return false;

            });         


$('#updateBtn').click(function(argtoUpdate){
        $.ajax({
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: {'vocalize_name' : argtoUpdate},
                url: 'http://tales.appedoncp.com/appcp/sanchita/api/getWordsFromVocalizeId.php',
                success: function(result)
                {

                console.log(result);
                    /*for(var i=0; i<result.name.length; i++)
                        {
                         $("#center_brp3").append("<div id=\"word\"" + [i]+ " class=\"sample_words\">" + result.name[i] + "</div><br>");
                        }*/

                },
                error: function(e)
                {


                }
        });
        });
```

I looked at other similar questions here but couldn't find a relevant solution.

Comment: Can we see a sample response?

Comment: Thanks @bfavaretto for your time. But I found the problem. 

It worked when I declared the artoUpdate as global variable and removed it from the updatebtn click function.

Was working on it since 6 hours but found the mistake only seconds after I asked it here.

Comment: @sanvj, that's the way a lot of problems work. As soon as you ask, you find the solution yourself :P